# How to integrate exponential and power function?

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(ax+bx^c)}\,dx  ; ~~~a,b,c>0.$$

I tried using partial functions but that didn't lead to anything.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Given that that does not have a closed form for $c=2$ (except using the error function or normal cdf or when $a=0$), what makes you think it might have a solution?